# Java HashSet worst case lookup time complexity

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, big-o, hashset

If hashtables/maps with closed hashing are worst-case `O(n)`, are HashSets also going to require `O(n)` time for lookup, or is it constant time?

Comment: In the worst case, yes, O(n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When looking up an element in a `HashMap`, it performs an O(1) calculation to find the right bucket, and then iterates over the items there serially until it finds the one the is equal to the requested key, or all the items are checked.

In the worst case scenario, all the items in the map have the same hash code and are therefore stored in the same bucket. In this case, you'll need to iterate over all of them serially, which would be an O(n) operation.

A `HashSet` is just a `HashMap` where you don't care about the values, only the keys - under the hood, it's a `HashMap` where all the values are a dummy `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of a `HashSet` (e.g. from OpenJDK 8:  https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java), you can see that it's actually just built on top of a `HashMap`.  Relevant code snippet here:

```
public class HashSet<E>

    extends AbstractSet<E>

    implements Set<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable

{
    private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

    // Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map

    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();

    /**

     * Constructs a new, empty set; the backing <tt>HashMap</tt> instance has

     * default initial capacity (16) and load factor (0.75).

     */

    public HashSet() {

        map = new HashMap<>();

    }

    public boolean add(E e) {

        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;

    }
```

The `HashSet` attempts to slightly optimize the memory usage by creating a single static empty Object value named `PRESENT` and just using that as the value part of every key/value entry into the `HashMap`.

So whatever the performance implications are of using a `HashMap`, a `HashSet` will have  more or less the same ones since it's literally using a `HashMap` under the covers.

To directly answer your question: in the worst case, yes, just as a the worse case complexity of a `HashMap` is `O(n)`, so too the worst case complexity of a `HashSet` is `O(n)`.

It is worth noting that, unless you have a really bad hash function or are using a hashtable of a ridiculously small size, you're very unlikely to see the worst case performance in practice.  You'd have to have every element hash to the exact same bucket in the hashtable so the performance would essentially degrade to a linked list traversal (assuming a hashtable using chaining for collision handling, which the Java ones do).

Comment: Well, this is interesting. Why does it use a HashMap under the hood? I would've thought that perhaps a HashMap uses a HashSet under the hood, if anything. What exactly do the key, value pairs turn into with a HashSet?

Comment: It's essentially the key with a value of an empty object.  If you scroll through that source and look through the class you can see a static member `private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();` and then the corresponding `Put(...)` method for the `HashSet` just does `public boolean add(E e) { return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null; }`.  Since only one instance of `PRESENT` exists in memory, the overhead is pretty minimal since ALL entries reference the same one `PRESENT` object.

Comment: As to the "why" part, my guess is that if you designed a `HashSet` that didn't have a value, then it'd be tough to re-use it for a `HashMap`.  On the flipside, you can do everything a `HashSet` does with a `HashMap`, so reusing it and just minimizing the memory overhead on the value part of the key/value pair makes sense to me.  You could almost certainly make a more efficient `HashSet` by itself, but I guess the memory vs. code reuse discussion the Java developers had landed in favor of code reuse.  (I never worked on Java itself, so this is all just speculation on my behalf)

Answer (score 0):

Worst case is O(N) as mentioned, average and amortized run time is constant.

From GeeksForGeeks:
The underlying data structure for HashSet is hashtable. So amortize (average or usual case) time complexity for add, remove and look-up (contains method) operation of HashSet takes O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people saying the worst case is O(n). This is because the old HashSet implementation used to use a LinkedList to handle collisions to the same bucket. However, that is not a definitive answer.

In java 8 such LinkedList is replaced by a balanced binary tree when the number of collisions of a bucket grows. This improves the worst-case performance from O(n) to O(log n) for lookups.

You can check additional details here.

- http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180
- https://www.nagarro.com/en/blog/post/24/performance-improvement-for-hashmap-in-java-8